# Word problem of Arithmetic Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

This question is taken from  my text book, given in the Arithmetic Series exercise.
I don't how to find the days using Arithmetic series?

Q: A besieged fortress is held by 5700 men who have provisions for 60 days. If the garrison loses 20 men each day, for how many days will the  provision last?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

@zonnie

Each guy eats $\frac{1}{342000}$ of the food per day. So we have the sum

$$\frac{\sum _{k=0}^d (5700-20 k)}{342000}=1$$

The sum in the numerator is easy and the whole thing becomes

$$-\frac{(d-570) (d+1)}{34200}= 1 $$

solving the quadratic we get

$$d = 66.99080479207322, d = 502.0091952079268 $$

The second answer is meaningless so the food should hold out for 66 full days and on the 67th day they are hungry. But since we called the first day 0 ( in the sum ) we should add 1 so they will last 67 days and on the 68th they are out.

Answer (score 2):

There are food for $5700\times 60=342 000$ days for 1 man.

$1$-st day they'll eat $5700$ daily food-items ($a_1=5700$).

$2$-nd day  they'll eat $5680$ daily food-items ($a_2=5680$).

$n$-th day $...$ $a_n=5700-20(n-1)$, ($n\le 285$, to have non-negative values of $a_n$).

If denote $$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_n,$$ then $\Rightarrow$ condition:
$$S_n\le 342000.$$

Sum of arithmetic progression is:
$$
S_n=\dfrac{a_1+a_n}{2}\cdot n = \dfrac{5700+5720-20n}{2}\cdot n = (5710-10n)n,
$$
so we get
$$
(5710-10n)n\le342000;
$$

$$
10n^2-5710n+342000\ge 0;
$$

for $n=67$ we have $S_n=337680<342000$,

for $n=68$ we have $S_n=342040>342000$.

Comment: I upvoted yours because it looks neater than mine and you did not have to do a sum no matter how easy but please edit the RHS of the last 2 lines.

Comment: Thanks Oleg567.. But in my book answer is 76 days.. so what does it means?

Comment: @zonnie, I really have no idea why answer can be $76$ days. Almost obviously that they'll eat 57000+5680+... ,  while sum will reach total food amount (342000). If they'd loose 32 soldiers every day, then I'd expected answer 76.

Comment: @zonnie or if they eat the food in 66 days rather then 60 then you would get 76 as the exact answer.

Comment: Yes thanks bobbym. Oleg567 explained it very well.. thanks to both of you.

Answer (score -1):

I think the assumption being made is that each man eats a constant amount of food each day, call it $r$. The statement that they have provisions for $60$ days is supposed to be interpreted as saying that, if the number of men remained constant, they would last $60$ days at that rate. So they have $60\cdot5700\cdot r$ units of food.

If $x_n$ is the amount of men still alive on day $n$, then on that day they'll eat $rx_n$ units of food. Can you work out the formula for $x_n$ and use that to figure out when they'll have eaten the $60\cdot5700\cdot r$ units they started with?